# Is "hi-speed internet" the same as "broadband"?

Tags: united-states, internet, fcc

[FCC.gov regulates broadband in the United States, and as of early 2015, they define it as 25 Mbps download with 3 Mbps upload (up from 4 and 1, respectively, that it used to be prior to 2015).](http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/29/7932653/fcc-changed-definition-broadband-25mbps)

But a lot of people generally refer to non-dial-up internet as "hi-speed internet", you don't really see "broadband" in any promotional materials.

Is "hi-speed internet", legally, the same as "broadband"?  Or is it a loophole word that's non-regulated and means nothing?

Comment: `you don't really see "broadband" in any promotional materials.` Really? I see it super frequently.

Answer (score 2):

According to the FCC Encyclopedia, [Types of Broadband Connections](https://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/types-broadband-connections):

> The term broadband commonly refers to high-speed Internet access that is always on and faster than the traditional dial-up access. Broadband includes several high-speed transmission technologies such as:
>
> - Digital Subscriber Line (DSL)
> - Cable Modem
> - Fiber
> - Wireless
> - Satellite
> - Broadband over Powerlines (BPL)

So yes, it is. High-speed is essentially synonymous to broadband under this definition. Companies likely use high-speed in advertising more often because most non-tech people out there buying Internet services won't know what broadband means. But whatever high-speed Internet technology the company is using, it all falls under the broadband regulations.

Comment: so, if a hotel or apartment complex advertises hi-speed internet, but you only get 1Mbps (or, basically, anything below 25 down and 3 up), is that legally false advertising?

Comment: @cnst that seems like a separate question.

Comment: @jimsug, why would that be a separate question?  what would be the legal point of the original question, then?

Comment: @cnst I'm not sure what you mean by _legal point_. However, to answer your first question: although you can ask follow up questions (and users can answer them), comments aren't searchable, so you'd need to edit your question as well. it doesn't apply in this case, but when you edit a question, it doesn't notify other answerers, who might end up feeling cheated, or whose answers now look inadequate, because you only commented on _one_ answer. But, Law.SE is finding its feet. Maybe we'll just let these things happen and see where it goes :)